# How to use weight in a Button to align Text on the left and Icon on the right

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-button, android-jetpack-compose-button

I'm building a re-usable Button component in Jetpack Compose, which is basically a `Row`. The button should have a text on the left end and an icon on the right end. This works straight forward like this:

```
@Composable
fun MyButton(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Button(
        onClick = { /* */ },
        modifier = modifier
    ) { // RowScope
        Text(
            text = text
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(
                id = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info
            ),
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }
}
```

However, if the button gets applied a fixed width, the text & icon is centered and not at the left/right end.

[image]

So I tried adding `modifier = Modifier.weight(1F)` to the `Text` so it fills up any additional space. But this causes a button without a fixed width to take up as much space as it can.

[image]

How can I build a Compose component that works in both cases: When a width is defined and when it is wrap-to-content?

My screen layout:

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
        MyButton(
            text = "variable width",
            modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth()
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
        MyButton(
            text = "fixed width",
            modifier = Modifier.width(300.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content of a `Button` is a `RowScope`.Just apply a `weight(1f)` modifier to the `Text` together with `TextOverflow.Ellipsis`.

Something like:

```
Button(
    onClick = { /* */ },
    modifier = modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)
) { // RowScope
    Text(
        text = text,
        maxLines = 1,
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
    Icon(
        painter = painterResource(
            id = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info
        ),
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to set an intrinsic width on your Button.
Something like

```
Button(
        onClick = { /* */ },
        modifier = modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
    )
```

See the documentation here, https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements